# Shopify update customer tags using api

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

How can a customer update is own customer[tags] ?

i tried using jquery.ajax to the api but it return XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' header is present on the requested resource.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://mydomain.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/customers/'+__st.cid+'.json',
    data: '{"customer": {"id": '+__st.cid+',"tags": "lng:fr"}}',
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Customers don't have access to their tags. They can't and should not update them directly using Admin API from their account!

The correct way would be creating a [custom app](https://shopify.dev/concepts/apps#custom-apps) with a [proxy](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension) URL pointing to an endpoint to do that. By doing that you don't expose the Shopify access token to the public and you can validate the request to be sure that it came from Shopify from that specific customer.

The way you're trying to do that is not correct anyway because it would allow anybody to update or even delete all customers from your store - don't do that.

Comment: Why Shopify don't verify that the updated user match the current user ? This won't allow anybody to update or delete all customers.

Comment: You want to make the Ajax request right from your Shopify website which means the Shopify API access token will be exposed to the public. If somebody can get it from your Ajax request, he will be able t do anything the access token has access to. You don't want this. The API keys like that should never be available to anyone.

Comment: When the request comes to Shopify API endpoint - they verify whether the access token is valid. In this case, they can't and should not verify whether the customer is authorized. You're accessing **Admin API**, it's not supposed to be accessed by the public directly.

Comment: I understand, but why a connected customer could not update is own profile calling api without access token while they let them update their profile by adding hidden field on login form.

Comment: Because when a customer signs up or in - no API keys are exposed to the public. Yes, there is a feature to add customer tags via the registration form - it's just a feature and there's nothing in common with updating customer tags via API.